# RTSP with Qt and VLC

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming

I'm trying to use `Qt5` to view a `RTSP` flow in a `Windows 7` environment.

I read that `QtMultimedia` doesn't support `RTSP` (I did it well with videos of my computer and videos .mp4 on internet, but it doesn't seem to work with `RTSP`).

I can see the flow with `VLC`, so I came up with the idea of using [vlc-qt](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt)

I found a sample code describing a basic usage of the library :

https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt

In order to make it work, I needed to include the libvlc.lib.

However I'm getting compiling errors such as:

- `QX11EmbedContainer` not found
- `libvlc_exception_t` not found

It seems that the `libvlc_exception_t` is deprecated in the newest version of VLC.

Are there any other possibilities? I wish I could only use `Qt` to include a live stream in a `QWidget` but I have not found anything.